# Split a string into parts in efficient way

Tags: ruby, arrays

My code is here

```
str = "Early in his first term in office, Obama signed into law economic stimulus legislation in response"
arr= str.split(" ")
set_element= arr.each_cons(2).to_a
sub_str = set_element.map {|i| i.join(' ')}
```

If i have a big string like very big string then this process take 6.50 sec
because i want to this type of result

```
sub_str= ["Early in", "in his", "his first", "first term", "term in", "in office,", "office, Obama", "Obama signed", "signed into", "into law", "law economic", "economic stimulus", "stimulus legislation", "legislation in", "in response"]
```

Is it possible any another way with efficient way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use scan instead of split and you can get your word pairs directly.

```
s.scan(/\S+(?:\s+\S+)?/)
```

EDIT: Just to assure myself that this was relatively efficient, I made [a little micro-benchmark](https://gist.github.com/dbenhur/5219395).  Here's results for the answers seen to date:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]
10 times on string of size 2284879
                 user     system      total        real
original     4.180000   0.070000   4.250000 (  4.272856)
sergio       2.090000   0.000000   2.090000 (  2.102469)
dbenhur      1.050000   0.000000   1.050000 (  1.042167)
```

Comment: awesome i have no word for this

Answer (score 1):

```
set_element = arr.each_cons(2).to_a
```

The line above creates a ton of temporary objects that you don't need. Try this, should be faster:

```
str = "Early in his first term in office, Obama signed into law economic stimulus legislation in response"
arr = str.split(" ")
sub_str = arr.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(el, memo), idx|
  if idx % 2 == 0
    memo << el
  else
    memo.last << ' ' << el
  end

end

sub_str # => ["Early in", "his first", "term in", "office, Obama", "signed into", "law economic", "stimulus legislation", "in response"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. one step less :)

```
arr= str.scan(/\S+/)
s = []
arr.each_with_index { |x, i| s << (x + " " + arr[i + 1]) if arr[i+1] }
```